# Open current ongoing call from app android

Tags: android

I want to open the call screen while call in progress and the user is in my app ,

I've looked around and found two results:

```
Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON
```

and

```
Intent.ACTION_DIAL
```

Both going to the dialer and not the call on progress(using galaxy 8)

Any ideas on how to solve this ?

tnx

Comment: Do you have Notification Access in your App ?

Comment: I think I don't , but we can add permissions pretty freely

Comment: Well if CallUI is in front then it will come back once you fish your app i guess as said in below answer . But if call UI is already in recent stack then it will not come back to front(i think but never tested it) . AND Notification Access is a special permission not some random one it only enables by user .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your scenario but just in case your app is on top of Dial App in stack of Activities then **finish your activity**. By doing this On Call screen will come on the top and will be displayed.

Comment: It's a good idea as a last resort , I want to keep it open if I can